# Open a directory using string variable in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a small GUI with 2 buttons where the first button allows a user to select a directory and the second button then opens up the directory chosen by the first button. So far, I've managed to create create a dialog where a user select a directory, and then the directory location is then stored as a string. I'm having issues passing the string as a reference. I've looked around and tried open a folder using the following line but with no luck.

```
f = open('%s' % folder_path, 'wb')
```

My current code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

def selectDirectory():
    global dirname
    global folder_path
    dirname = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory')
    folder_path.set(dirname)
    print(dirname)
folder_path=StringVar()

def fileopen():
    f = open('%s' % folder_path, 'wb')

# Creating buttons
selectFolder = Button(root, text = "Select directory", command = selectDirectory)
selectFolder.grid(row=0,column=0)

openfile = Button(root, text = "Open folder", command = fileopen)
openfile.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Also any advice relating to how I could improve this code would be greatly appreciated. I've just recently started out learning Python.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, `folder_path()` is a `StringVar` - you need to call `.get()` on it to actually retrieve its value, just as you had to use `.set()` to store that value.  But calling `open()` on a directory is meaningless - what were you expecting that to do?

Comment: You should use `folder_path.get()` to retrieve the value stored in it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I was hoping `open()` would open the directory. I'll try using `.get` and attempt to get it working.

Comment: Does `open a directory` mean open a file explorer window with the the specified directory as the current directory?

Comment: Yes, so the directory that was selected with the first button is opened up on a file explorer. Jundullah's answer below works perfectly, however I'm still trying to utilise `.get()` in this situation.

Comment: Please note that `os.startfile()` works in Windows platform only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `open` function only applies to files!

way to open: `os.system(filepath)`

But if you want to open a folder, you can use `os.startfile`[ Windows]!

**example code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

def selectDirectory():
    global dirname
    global folder_path
    dirname = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select a 
directory')
    folder_path.set(dirname)
    print(dirname)
folder_path=StringVar()

def fileopen():
    os.system('%s.csv' % folder_path)

def folderopen():
    os.startfile(dirname)

# Creating buttons
selectFolder = Button(root, text = "Select directory", command = selectDirectory)
selectFolder.grid(row=0,column=0)

openfile = Button(root, text = "Open file", command = fileopen)
openfile.grid(row=1, column=0)

openfolder = Button(root, text = "Open folder", command = folderopen)
openfolder.grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```